# how to save a .unity file as a .unity3D

Tags: file, unity-game-engine, save, file-type

As part of my university project, I am to upload a game that I have made at university, and it is advised that we first upload to Kongregate (as the comments there will provide feedback)
It appears that I can only upload a .unity3D file, whereas the game of which I have made is saved as a .unity file (which was regarded as an invalid file), and today I tried to save it as a .unity3D file, but not even older versions would allow me to save it as a .unity3D file.

Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: "but not even older versions would allow me to save it as a .unity3D file." What versions have you tried? How are you trying to save out to  .unity3D?

Comment: in university, we have version 5 and 4, and lots of different versions of those
in all the older versions, my game doesn't seem to load properly (it just loads what appears to be a blank scene)